# Bluetooth in Ubuntu not working

Tags: usb, bluetooth

After typing:- `dmesg | grep bluetooth`   I got the following errors:-

```
[  347.025774] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  347.025815] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized    
[  347.027047] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized    
[  347.027051] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  347.027057] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized    
[  347.063929] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[  347.063936] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Failed to suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[  347.131609] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  347.131614] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast  
[  347.131617] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

After typing:- `egrep '^(VERSION|NAME)=' /etc/os-release && uname -a && lsusb | grep Blue`     --- I got the following result:-

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
Linux zak-ubuntu 5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 14 00:32:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

Comment: _`Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...`_. Hmm... seems suspicious 

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: Please add to the question the output of the command in the terminal: egrep '^(VERSION|NAME)=' /etc/os-release && uname -a && lsusb | grep Blue

Comment: It seems like this is being fixed here: https://lkml.org/lkml/2022/3/5/32